# how to bind vector.resize

Tags: c++, boost, bind, blitz++

I try to use `boost::bind` with `std::vector<>::resize`.

But the following code won't compile:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace boost;

int main(){
    typedef std::vector<double> type;
    type a;
    bind(&type::resize, _1, 2)(a);
    return 0;
}
```

So, how can I do this?

Thanks!

**boost version 1.53
gcc version 4.8 or 4.6**

**Edit: ** The above code works with -std=c++11. In fact, my original problem is this:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace boost;
using namespace blitz;

int main(){
    typedef Array<double, 1> type;
    type a;
            //a.resize(4) is ok;
    bind(&type::resize, _1, 2)(a);
    return 0;
}
```

My compile command is:
g++ t.cpp -I path/include/ -std=c++11 -L path/lib/ -l blitz

Comment: Works fine [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2QMK7q$10). Are you showing the real code?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. Because my gcc compile output is not english, I cannot paste here...

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, your code compiles. Try a different compiler maybe, or translate the error

Comment: `bind(&type::resize, _1, 2)(a);` works fine with -std=c++11     `bind(&type::resize, _1, 2, 0.0)(a);` works fine without. [std::vector::resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on cppreference.

Comment: You are right! resize starts from c++11 ... Thanks!

Comment: No, `resize` is in C++03, but the signature specified in the standard changed from one function with two arguments (with a default value) to a pair of overloads

Comment: would be interesting to see the compile output after putting it through babelfish!

Comment: To get the compiler output in english just run `LANG= g++` instead of `g++`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Could you please explain more clearly? I have not used it before. Thanks!

Comment: explain what more clearly? getting English output? GCC checks the environment to decide what language to print output in, if you want to override your environment setting so it defaults to English then set `LANG` to an empty string or to `C`, which you can do by running `LANG=C g++ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Where do I put 'LANG= g++'? Environment variable?

Comment: No, re-read what I wrote! I've already said it twice! Put it at the start of the compiler command. You could set `LANG=C` in your environment but that would affect other programs too, so to only affect GCC temporarily just put it before the compiler command

Comment: For [blitz::array](http://blitz.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/blitz/blitz/file/ab84372f3dce/blitz/array-impl.h#l1047), following JonathanWakely's answer, I think you would need `bind(static_cast<void (type::*)(int)>(&type::resize), _1, 2)(a);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`resize` might be an overloaded function (in C++11 it has to be) so you need to tell the compiler which overload you want. For the one argument form, this should work in C++11:

```
bind(static_cast<void (type::*)(type::size_type)>(&type::resize), _1, 2)(a);
```

Or more readably:

```
typedef void (type::*resize_signature)(type::size_type);
bind(static_cast<resize_signature>(&type::resize), _1, 2)(a);
```

If it's *not* an overloaded function (as with GCC in C++03 mode) then it takes two arguments (one has a default value) and you need to supply the second argument because `bind` can't use default arguments:

```
typedef void (type::*resize_signature)(type::size_type, const value_type&);
bind(static_cast<resize_signature>(&type::resize), _1, 2, 0.0)(a);
```

Unfortunately this C++03 version isn't portable, implementations are allowed to use a single function or a pair of overloads. To make it portable, or to work with other types such as `Array` you can wrap the call in a custom functor that calls `resize`, so you don't need to know the exact signature:

```
typename<class VecT>
struct resizer<VecT> {
    void operator()(VecT& v, unsigned n) const { v.resize(n); }
};
// ...
bind(resizer<type>(), _1, 2)(a);
```

Or in C++11 just use a lambda expression instead of `bind`:

```
auto resize = [](type& v) { v.resize(2); };
resize(a);
```

Comment: In fact, I have tested the 3rd method, it indeed works. I really cannot understand why 'a.reszie(2)' works, while 'bind(&type::resize, _1, 2)(a);' doesn't work.

Comment: I explained why it doesn't work, `&type::resize` is an overloaded function, so you need to tell the compiler which overload you want to use.  When you call `a.resize(2)` it knows which overload you want because it knows what arguments you're using. When you say `&type::resize` it doesn't know.

Comment: I got it. So, lambda expression is more convenient in this phase?